# How I can grab all public function methods in a controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I use `__remap()` function to avoid any undefine method and make it redirect to index() function.

```
function __remap($method)
{
   $array = {"method1","method2"};
   in_array($method,$array) ? $this->$method() : $this->index();
}
```

That function will check if other than method1 and method2.. it will redirect to index function.

Now, how I can automatically grab all **public function** methods  in that controller instead of manually put on `$array` variable?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I was bored:

```
$r = new ReflectionClass(__CLASS__);
$methods = array_map(function($v) {
                        return $v->name;
                     },
                     $r->getMethods(ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to test if method exists and is public. So you need use reflection and method exists. Something like this:

```
function __remap($method)
{
    if(method_exists($this, $method)){
        $reflection = new ReflectionMethod($this, $method);
        if($reflection->isPublic()){
            return $this->{$method}();
        }
    }

    return $this->index();
}
```

Or you can use get_class_methods() for create your array of methods

Answer (score 0):

I've modified the codes and become like this.

```
function _remap($method)
{
    $controllers = new ReflectionClass(__CLASS__);
    $obj_method_existed = array_map(function($method_existed) 
            {
            return $method_existed;
            },
    $controllers->getMethods(ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC));

    $arr_method = array();
    //The following FOREACH I think was not good practice.

    foreach($obj_method_existed as $method_existed):
        $arr_method[] = $method_existed->name;
    endforeach;

    in_array($method, $arr_method) ? $this->$method() : $this->index();
}
```

Any enhancement instead of using **foreach**?

Comment: By the way, how I can also avoid the method's name started with `_` or `__` ? For example `_remap()` or `__construct()`, etc..